# How can I build a password with 2 random lowercase, uppercase, numbers and punctuation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, passwords

I want to build a strong password generator with Python and strong password would be 2 lowercase chars, 2 uppercase chars, 2 numbers, 2 symbols. The strong part gives me error. Too many positional arguments for method call on random in the while

```
# Password generator
import random
import string


def create_waek_pass():
    password = random.randint(10000000, 99999999)
    print(f"password : {password}")


def create_strong_pass():
    password = []
    for i in range(2):
        lower = [string.ascii_lowercase]  # i wanted to create a list with 2 lower case chars
        upper = [string.ascii_uppercase] 
        number = [random.randint(0, 9)]
        exclimations = [string.punctuation]

    while len(password) <= 8:
        password = random.choice(lower, upper, number, exclimations)
    print(password)
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. In the for loop you just keep shadowing the same names with a list containing a single thing (e.g. `['abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz']`). Then in the whole loop you keep trying to *replace* the whole password value. I'd guess the error is that choice only takes a single value, but you have deeper algorithm problems.

Comment: "the strong part gives me error" - Any reason for not including a description of that error?

Comment: i wanted to create a list of lower case with 2 chars from a to z

Comment: The question is why, looking at your code its clear you probably dont have much experience in python so prob have even less experience in security. So i would say dont try and write your own. There are a lot more people out there with greater security knowledge so let them do that work

Comment: it is just a training i am trying to do for my own

Comment: should the groups, lower, upper etc return 2 unique chars, or can they contain the same chars? like if i take 2 chars from lower can they be `aa` or they must be two different chars?

Comment: they can be the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i said in my comment its never a good idea to role your own security functions as security is a complex space and should be left to professionals. however you said this is just for your own training / learning so below is an example of your code but modified to work. This is by no means a well thought design, i have simply taken your code and made it work.

```
# Password generator
from random import shuffle, choice
import string

def create_strong_pass():
    lower = string.ascii_lowercase
    upper = string.ascii_uppercase
    number = string.digits
    punctuation = string.punctuation
    password = []
    for _ in range(2):
        password.append(choice(lower))
        password.append(choice(upper))
        password.append(choice(number))
        password.append(choice(punctuation))
    shuffle(password)
    return "".join(password)

for _ in range(10):
    print(create_strong_pass())
```

**OUTPUT**

```
b7B#eR?7
)V2be7!Y
3Hng7_;V
q\/mDU74
Ii03/tW:
0Md6i;K@
<:LHw0b6
2eoM&V`6
c09N)Za(
t:34T'Bo
```